# PHP error.log file showing so many NUL lines in Mac

Tags: php, error-logging, error-log

I am working on a mac machine running `macOS 13` and using `PHP 7.3`. When the error_log is using, along with that so many `NUL` showing in the log file in red background. The file size getting enormously big and I am not getting why this is coming. Adding a screenshot below

[image]

Any lead to avoid this will be a great help.

below is the log I added using error_log.

> [02-Mar-2023 10:22:37 UTC] {"status":"default","message":"common.pushRequestToLog","paramsStr":"msg: %s","paramsArr":{},"errorMessage":"","request_id":"4cea740955cd3d4bdd574b45dcd861ba","token":"","archetypeId":"","projectId":"","host":"","defaultView":"","clientId":"","clientName":"","exerciseId":"","sessionType":"","childSessionType":"","levels":"","userDetails":"","currentProblem":"","clientUserId":"","orgId":""}

Comment: What is the last actual error reported before one of these nul sets?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, below is the log I added using error_log.   `[02-Mar-2023 10:22:37 UTC] {"status":"default","message":"common.pushRequestToLog","paramsStr":"msg: %s","paramsArr":{},"errorMessage":"","request_id":"4cea740955cd3d4bdd574b45dcd861ba","token":"","archetypeId":"","projectId":"","host":"","defaultView":"","clientId":"","clientName":"","exerciseId":"","sessionType":"","childSessionType":"","levels":"","userDetails":"","currentProblem":"","clientUserId":"","orgId":""}`

Comment: Well put that into the question, using the EDIT link under the question. Nobody can read things like that in a comment

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)